# Should i clear the seams?

Tags: uv, texture-painting

When I go to texture models I sometimes notice small black lines from the seams I created during the process of UV unwrapping, I figure the logical course of action would be to clear the seams, but I'm not sure, Should I?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would advise against it. In the case that you need to adjust your UV map, you would have to start from scratch. If it is distracting you, you can toggle the visibility of seams. [image]

Comment: Ahhh thank you! but uhhh, will this clear the black lines when I render the model?

Comment: Seams shouldn't be visible when you render. It is only a viewport visualization.

Comment: Oh Okay, Molte grazie!